# i want to create a Piechart by using datatable plugin as a data in Jquery

Tags: javascript

I want to create a piechart on the web page to be displayed , by using datatable plugin as a data in jquery .
So,below is the code for the Piechart where the data is entered manually as a json data.

```
  <script src="js/highcharts.j`enter code here`s" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var chart;
        $(document).ready(function() {
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'browser_cart',
                    plotBackgroundColor: null,
                    plotBorderWidth: null,
                    plotShadow: false
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2010'
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.percentage +' %';
                    }
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    pie: {
                        allowPointSelect: true,
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            color: '#000000',
                            connectorColor: '#000000',
                            formatter: function() {
                                return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.percentage +' clicks';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    type: 'pie',
                    name: 'Browser share',
                    data: [
                        ['Firefox',   45],
                        ['IE',       26],
                        ['Chrome',   12], 
                        ['Safari',    8],
                        ['Opera',     6],
                        ['Others',   7]
                    ]
                }]
            });
        });

    </script>

</head>
<body>


    <!-- 3. Add the container -->
    <div id="browser_cart" style="width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>


</body>
```

I got an Error messaage --> "Highcharts is not defined.
                            Merge is not a function."

Answer (score 1):

You have an typo:

```
<script src="js/highcharts.j`enter code here`s" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Should be:

```
<script src="js/highcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: o sorry highcharts.js is the right one,but when i copied it may been.

Comment: Are you sure there is `highcharts.js` file in `js` folder?

Comment: one of the error code is got solved,but the other error - Merge is not a function is not solved.

Comment: Which version of highcharts are you using?

Comment: Maybe try to download new 2.2.1 vesion

Comment: highcharts 2.2.0 is the latest one . 1st error is solved by changing merging the two javascript tags.

Comment: On official site and on github latest version is 2.2.1 http://www.highcharts.com/download https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com

Comment: Only include highcharts.js in the code or i need to other exporting.js

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script src="js/highcharts.j`enter code here`s" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I feel `enter code here` is not required at all...
Just check with address

Comment: yes, but while editing the code ,i have enter the code wrong one .